# Unable to connect to net core gRPC service hosted in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, grpc

I am relatively new to gRPC service.

I am trying to deploy a **Net core gRPC service** into Linux docker container and accessing it from locally from **VS console app**.

I want to keep things as simple as possible thus the docker file is identical to a Net core gRPC docker file in VS where docker compose is pointing to it. When running the gRPC service in VS directly, the console app can access the service, just not in docker container.

gRPC launch settings

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "TrafficGrpc": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

gRPC app settings

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  }
}
```

Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["gRPC/TrafficGrpc/TrafficGrpc.csproj", "TrafficGrpc/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TrafficGrpc/TrafficGrpc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/gRPC/TrafficGrpc"
RUN dotnet build "TrafficGrpc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TrafficGrpc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TrafficGrpc.dll"]
```

Docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  # Traffic service
  traffic:
    container_name: traffic
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-traffic
    networks:
      grpc_network:
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=1
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:32773:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:32774:443"
      
networks:
  grpc_network:
```

Console app, VS

```
string trafficUrl = "http://localhost:32773";
//string trafficUrl = "https://localhost:32774";

Traffic traffic = new Traffic
{
    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    Area = Areas[rng.Next(Areas.Length)],
    Condition = Conditions[rng.Next(Conditions.Length)]
};

GrpcChannel tChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(trafficUrl);
TrafficCheckerClient tClient = new TrafficCheckerClient(tChannel);
TrafficConditionResponse tReply = await tClient.CheckTrafficConditionAsync(
    new TrafficConditionRequest { Condition = traffic.Condition }); // <-- ERROR here
```

After running docker-compose file, the console app is just not able to connect to gRPC.

Using http, I get this error:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The response ended prematurely.")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ConsoleTestgRPC.Program.<Main>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\Workspace-GW-EV\CL\ConsoleTestgRPC\Program.cs:line 61
```

Using https, I get this error:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ConsoleTestgRPC.Program.<Main>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\Workspace-GW-EV\CL\ConsoleTestgRPC\Program.cs:line 61
```

At this point, I do not know whether it is a docker network or a gRPC config issue.

I need help to point me in the right direction.

THANK YOU

Comment: I see localhost being used, which should work when running locally, but I don't believe that is the case when you deploy into the container.  if you are exposing the service on 0.0.0.0 in the container, it will expose it on all container interfaces.  I have only done this in windows containers, but I am assuming this is the case as well with Linux as well

Comment: I can't get this to work either. The comment below looks like it has promise but I still can't get it to work

Answer (score 2):

I meet familiar problem today.

You set EXPOSE 80 in the dockerfile, so you need to make grpc to listen the port which bind to it.

So in my case, the grpc listen to the 8099, and expose it to host port: 32812, then client creat channel to it. And it work.

In dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8099
EXPOSE 443
```

In server to listen port:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(
                        8099,
                        listenOptions => { listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2; }
                    );
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

In client to create channel:

```
GrpcClientFactory.AllowUnencryptedHttp2 = true;

using var http = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:32812");
```

[Binding port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSlJS.png)

May this will help you, good luck~

Comment: Please include your code as text within your answer instead of screenshotting it

Comment: Any chance you could include more details here? What was the docker run command you used? What is the significance of 443? Can't that be removed? AllowUnencryptedHttp2  no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

I Had some problems to run the image on kubernetes. To Fix:

1 - To expose port i had to change on image and appliation and expose the Enviroment var(but only EXPOSE works too).

[image]

Force the port
[image]

2 - My issue was the certificate on TLS protocol (i did't had). I has publicated on my github how i fixed it without certificate. But take atention on the enviroment. This exemple can be applied only on internal comunication with ClusterIp. It's a insecure implementation mode to public exposition.

link fix(example)
https://github.com/davidsonsilvadev/grpc-core3.1-docker-kubernetes-without-certificate